# jQueryMobile can't get value of input textbox on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile

I have a simple jQM form with some inputs, the problem is I can't retrieve the value of an input through JS when testing on the iPhone, main desktop browsers are working.

Here's part of the form:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
   <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />


   <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />

   <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="validate()" />
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
function validate()
{
    alert('value: ' + $('#fname').val());
}
```

The alert shows literally as:

*value:*

Also tried using the traditional .value method.

Version in use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:** added more code for clarification.

Comment: is there information in the input? what is the full code included with the alert?

Comment: Added the simple JS function to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are in the document ready:

```
$(function(){
     alert($('#fname').val()); //should be nothing bc the input has no value yet
});
```

Comment: I should have mentioned my `alert()` is in a function that is called when the form is submitted so I know there is a value.

Comment: @Chris -- there are sometimes issues when the name and the id of an input tag are the same. try making it so that is not so

Comment: @Neal, found problem: jQM is pulling muliple instances of my form page (div) into the same overall page so there are confilcting element IDs, iPhone is reading the first, Firefox desktop reads the newest.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I was scratching my head.